# Graphically trace path of touch input; what ios framework to use?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, frameworks

I'm been developing for iOS for about 6 months now and have an idea for an app which reqires that the user touch input is traced on the screen.

My experience with iOS development is solely with navigation-style application so I've never had to deal with any graphical frameworks.

So my question is what framework(s) should I use the accomplish this?

The path tracing will be the only graphical part of the app so I feel that some game-development frameworks like openGL ES and cocos2d may be overkill; but then again I don't know.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to use `CGPathRef`/`CGMutablePathRef`/`UIBezierPath`, which are part of Quartz and UIKit (which you should already be familiar with.) Use the touch points to construct your path. Create a subclass of `UIView`, and in its `-drawRect:` method, draw the path.

Does that help?